# Proper login architecture with Firebase then (Instagram) in Flutter

Tags: flutter, authentication, architecture, firebase-authentication

Let me explain what I'm trying to do. I have an app that users Firebase to authenticate users. When a user logs in, though, the user has to link an Instagram account in order to proceed (the app does things with Instagram data). The question is not about how to do the actual login with either Firebase or Instagram, the question is about how to structure my app so the workflow works. My current workflow relies on a root page listening on a stream for changes in the Firebase user and returns the corresponding page depending on the situation. This is not really what I want for two reasons. 1) It's broken; the pages don't actually return when they're supposed to (this might be because I have a FutureBuilder inside a StreamBuilder so it's getting confused?). If I reload the app, however, the state did change and it loads the correct page. 2) Doing this I have to go directly from the create account page to the linking page. I want to go back to the login page in order to confirm accounts by sending an email *before* proceeding with the Instagram linking process. In summary, here's some pseudocode for what I'm trying to do:

```
Root Page:
    If user is logged in:
        Go to Link Decider
    Else:
        Go to (Firebase) Login Page

Link Decider:
    If user is logged in with Instagram:
        Go to Home Page
    If user has Instagram account linked to Firebase but is not logged in:
        Go to Log in with Instagram Page
    If user hasn't linked Instagram:
        Go to Link Instagram Page

Instagram Link/Login Pages:
    Do login then go to Home Page
```

Sorry for the long question I've just been trying a lot of things and nothing seems to work so I figured someone else might have a better idea of how to do this. If you want to see some concrete implementation I can add it but I don't think it's necessary (since I'm trying to do this a better way not fix my wacky one). Any help is very much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want my opinion, follow the Flutter Firebase & DDD Course series in the below link. I have learned a lot from this website with regards to architecting your application 
[Flutter Firebase & DDD Course](https://resocoder.com/2020/03/09/flutter-firebase-ddd-course-1-domain-driven-design-principles/)